# Check if the given sequence is valid bfs or not?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph-theory, breadth-first-search

I am trying to implement a valid BFS question, that is check if the given sequence is a valid BFS path or not?. But I am not able to keep a track of the arbitrary sequence of the path.

Here is the code that I have written. I is giving me wrong output for this particular sequence.

```
from collections import deque


class Solution(object):
    def is_valid_bfs(self, n, edges, sequence):
        #n is number of nodes

        #Build the graph in the form of an adjacency list using edges
        adjacency_list = dict()

        for edge in edges:
            x , y = edge[0], edge[1]
            if x not in adjacency_list:
                adjacency_list[x] = [y]
            else:
                adjacency_list[x].append(y)
            
            if y not in adjacency_list:
                adjacency_list[y] = [x]
            else:
                adjacency_list[y].append(x)
        
        #Perform BFS from 1st node 

        queue = deque()
        visited = set()
    
        queue.append(1)
        visited.add(1)

        path = []
        
        while queue:
            node = queue.popleft()
            path.append(node)

            for neighbor in adjacency_list[node]:
                if neighbor not in visited:
                    queue.append(neighbor)
                    visited.add(neighbor)
        
        return path == sequence
    

n = 4 
edges = [[1,2],[1,3],[1,4]]
sequence = [1,3,2,4]

obj = Solution()

print(obj.is_valid_bfs(n, edges, sequence))
```

Can someone please suggest me how do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The builing of the adjacency list is fine.

The problem is that your BFS algorithm *enforces* that the children of a node are visited in one particular order. It should instead look at the sequence *while* performing BFS, to check which child to visit first, second, ...etc.

Also, your code assumes that node 1 is the node at which the traversal started. You should instead read that value from the given sequence.

Here is a correction of the second part of your code:

```py
        queue = deque()
        visited = set()

        it = iter(sequence)  # Create iterator over sequence
        root = next(it)      # Get which root to start at
        queue.append(root)
        visited.add(root)

        while queue:
            node = queue.popleft()

            neighbors = set(adjacency_list[node])  # Get the neighbors 
            neighbors -= visited   # ...and discard any nodes already visited
            while neighbors:  # While we have neighbors to visit...
                neighbor = next(it, None)   # Get which neighbor to visit now
                if neighbor not in neighbors:  # ...it must be one in our set
                    return False
                neighbors.discard(neighbor) # Remove it
                queue.append(neighbor)
                visited.add(neighbor)

        return not next(it, None)  # Require that sequence was completely iterated
```

Comment: In the question, it is given that the start node is 1. I don't have to change anything in the bfs implementation you showed right?

Comment: I got it! 

Instead of looping through the node's neighbors in a fixed order, it makes sense to loop through the input sequence and check if it is present in the set! 

Thanks a lot!